# A quotient of the general linear group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, quotient-spaces

I am very interested in finding the homology of the following space, call it $M$. We take the quotient of $GL(3,\mathbb R)$ by the equivalence relation that identifies two $A,B\in GL(3,\mathbb R)$ by saying that for any $i=1,2,3$ there is a non-zero scalar $\lambda_i \in \mathbb R$ such that the $i$th row of $B$ is a $\lambda$ multiple of the $i$th row of $A.$

This quotient space is very similar to the space $PGL(3,\mathbb R)$ which is the quotient of $GL(3,\mathbb R)$ by the equivalence relation that identifies two matrices that are nonzero scalar multiple, $M$ additionally identifies scaling of the rows.

If $M$ is a well-known space can you tell me what it is? I know the homology of $GL(3,\mathbb{R}),$ how can I calculate the homology of $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim. 1. $M$ is homotopy-equivalent to the quotient of $S^3$ by free (linear) action of the dihedral group $D_4$ (of order $8$).

2. Consequently, $H_0(M)\cong H_3(M)\cong {\mathbb Z}$, $H_1(M)\cong {\mathbb Z}_2\times  {\mathbb Z}_2$ and $H_2(M)=0$.

In particular, the space $M$ **does not** have homology groups isomorphic to that of $GL(3, {\mathbb R})$ (apart from the fact that $H_2$ vanishes in both cases).

Here is a sketch of the proof.

i. Using the QR decomposition, we obtain $GL(3, {\mathbb R})= U\cdot O(3)$, where $U$ is the subgroup of upper-triangular matrices with positive diagonal entries. As Lee Mosher noted in his answer, the quotient space $M$ is nothing but $GL(3, {\mathbb R})/T$, where $T$ is a *maximal torus* in $GL(3, {\mathbb R})$, the subgroup of diagonal matrices. The group $T$ deformation-retracts to its maximal compact subgroup $K_T=T\cap O(3)$ consisting of diagonal matrices with entries in $\{\pm 1\}$. From this, it follows that $M$ is homotopy-equivalent to $O(3)/K_T$.

ii. The group $O(3)$ has two components, one of which is $SO(3)$. From this, it follows that $O(3)/K_T$ is diffeomorphic to $Y=SO(3)/(K_T\cap SO(3))$, where $\Gamma=K_T\cap SO(3)\cong {\mathbb Z}_2\times  {\mathbb Z}_2$. Thus, we have to analyze the quotient of $SO(3)$ by that subgroup of order 4. The universal covering group of $SO(3)$ is $SU(2)$, which is diffeomorphic to $S^3$. One verifies that lifting $\Gamma$ to the covering space $S^3$ results in the group $\Gamma^*$ which is the nontrivial central extension of $\Gamma$ by the center of $SU(2)$, i.e.
$\Gamma^*$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$. In particular, the abelianization of $\Gamma^*$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma\cong {\mathbb Z}_2\times  {\mathbb Z}_2$.

iii. Now, I will compute homology of the quotient manifold $Y=S^3/\Gamma^*$. By the Hurewicz theorem,
$H_1(Y)$ is isomorphic to the abelianization of $\pi_1(Y)\cong \Gamma^*$. Hence, $H_1(Y)\cong {\mathbb Z}_2\times  {\mathbb Z}_2$. The manifold $Y$ is orientable (since $\Gamma^*$ is contained in $SU(2)$) and, obviously, compact and connected. This gives us  $H_0(M)\cong H_3(M)\cong {\mathbb Z}$, $H_1(M)\cong {\mathbb Z}_2\times  {\mathbb Z}_2$. To compute $H_2$, we use the Poincare Duality:
$$
H_2(Y)\cong H^1(Y). 
$$
The 1st cohomology group one computes using the [Universal Coefficients Theorem for Cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology). The Ext-term ($Ext(H_0(Y), {\mathbb Z})= Ext({\mathbb Z}, {\mathbb Z})$) vanishes and one is left with
$$
H^1(Y)\cong Hom(H_1(Y), {\mathbb Z})=0. 
$$
Thus, $H_2(Y)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand why $O(3)/K_T$ is diffeomorphic to $Y=SO(3)/(K_T\cap SO(3)),$ am I not supposed to have $O(3)/K_T \simeq Y\sqcup Y$ and take homology of this disjoint union.

Comment: @テレビスクリーン: Pick an  element of the  group $K_T$ with negative determinant, it will swap the two components of $O(3)$, hence, the two components of $O(3)/\Gamma$.

Comment: @Moishe_Kohan Sorry for bothering you again. I don't really understand why $Y$ is orientable because of the reason that $\Gamma^*$ is contained in $SU(2)$. For a quotient manifold to be orientable, we need to have that the group action is orientation preserving (right?), and I'm not sure how this is satisfied.

Comment: "For a quotient manifold to be orientable, we need to have that the group action is orientation preserving" is true if your group is acting on a **connected** manifold, but becomes an ambiguous statement if your group is acting on a disconnected manifold as in the example at hand. A manifold with two components has 4 different orientations.  A group element can reverse two of these orientations, but preserve the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer.

Your space falls into a well known *class* of spaces, namely homogeneous spaces of Lie groups, also known as coset spaces of a Lie group modulo a Lie subgroup. In any Lie group $G$, for any Lie subgroup $H < G$, there is an associated homogeneous space, namely the quotient space of right cosets
$$H \setminus G = \{Hg \mid g \in G\}
$$
In your case
$$H = \begin{pmatrix} 
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3
\end{pmatrix} \qquad G = GL(3,\mathbb R)
$$
It's called a *homogeneous space* for $G$ because the right action of $G$ on itself by multiplication descends to a transitive action of $G$ on $H \setminus G$.

There is always fibration of $G$ over $H \setminus G$ with fiber $H$.

In your case, the fiber $H$ is $(\mathbb R - \{0\})^3$ which has 8 components, each of which is homeomorphic to $(0,\infty)^3$ and is hence contractible. This is simple enough that one should be able to exactly relate the homology groups of $G$ to those of $H$.

I suspect, however, that this is not really a shortcut to computing the homology groups of $H \setminus G$.

I do know of methods for computing homology groups of certain homogeneous spaces by finding reasonably simple cell decompositions. There are certain homogeneous spaces of $GL(3,\mathbb R)$ called [Grassmanians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) for which there are well studied decompositions into [Schubert cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#Schubert_cells). These decompositions allow one to go on and do homological calculations for Grassmanians.

Your homogeneous spacs is not a Grassmanian, but perhaps similar techniques work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is very helpful. If the homology groups of $H\backslash G$ are isomorphic to that of $G,$ isn't the problem solved? I don't understand why it "is not really a shortcut to computing the homology groups of $H\backslash G.$ "

Comment: Well, sure, the problem is solved if you already know the homology groups of $G=GL(3,\mathbb R)$. You did not indicate in your post whether you already knew that.

Comment: Actually, the fiber $H$ is not contractible, it in not connected.

Comment: Oops, you're right, $\lambda_i$ can be positive or negative..