# Finding Cohomology of a Fiber Bundle from Serre Spectral Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I have a fiber bundle $F\rightarrow E\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^3$ and I know the cohomology groups of $F$ and $\mathbb{RP}^3,$ $H^0(F,\mathbb Z)=H^3(F,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$, $H^2(F,\mathbb Z)=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$ and other cohomology groups of $F$ are zero. Additionally, $H^0(\mathbb{RP}^3,\mathbb Z)=H^3(\mathbb{RP}^3,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z,$ $H^2(\mathbb{RP}^3,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and other cohomology groups of $\mathbb{RP}^3$ are zero. I know that the fiber $F$ is a compact connected orientable manifold but I don't know more about it. I have no information about the total space $E$ and I want to find its cohomology. The $E_2$ page of the corresponding Serre spectral sequence, from $E^{s,t}_2=H^{s}(\mathbb{RP}^3,H^t(F)),$ is as below. $$\begin{matrix} \mathbb Z & 0 & \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z & \mathbb Z \\ (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2 & (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2 & (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2 & (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \mathbb Z & 0 & \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z & \mathbb Z\end{matrix}$$ The only non-trivial differential is $d_2:E^{0,3}_2\rightarrow E_2^{2,2}$ and since it is a homomorphism from integers to $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$ it cannot be surjective, so $d_2$ survives. And so by degree reasons $E_\infty$ degenerates to $E_3$ where every term in $E_3$ is same as to that of $E_2$ except at the index $(2,2)$ which I don't really know what it is, $E_3^{2,2}$ is either $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$. I'm having difficulty calculating $E_3^{2,2}$. Since it is a Serre spectral sequence we say $E_2^{s,t}$ abuts to $H^{s+t}(E,\mathbb Z)$ but I couldn't find how to extract $H^{s+t}(E,\mathbb Z)$ from $E_\infty,$ is it generally the direct sum of terms $E_3^{i,s+t-i}=E_\infty^{i,s+t-i}$, if not, how to proceed?

Comment: Do you know that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ acts trivially on $H^*(F; \mathbb{Z})$? If not, you need to use cohomology with local coefficients.

Comment: I don't know how to verify that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ acts trivially on $H^*(F;\mathbb Z).$

Comment: If it will be helpful $F$ is the space $M$ in [my previous question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461136/a-quotient-of-the-general-linear-group)

Comment: I have no idea whether $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ has to act trivially or not. Your computation so far can be considered the relevant one under the additional assumption that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ acts trivially. If your fiber bundle is orientable, then $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^3)$ should act trivially on $H^3(F; \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Provided that the fundamental group acts trivially, how do I read off the cohomology groups of $E$ from $E_\infty,$ when there are multiple terms on a diagonal?

Comment: Even if the fundamental group acts non-trivially, $H^k(E)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of the groups $E^{p,q}_{\infty}$ with $p + q = k$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, I think that's only true if we're using $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (or some other field) coefficients everywhere but not if we're using integer coefficients. Or have I missed something about this specific case?

Comment: @kamills: Of course you are correct, I was being sloppy. We only know that there is a filtration of $H^k(E)$ and the groups $E^{p,q}_{\infty}$ with $p + q = k$ are the associated graded groups as in Theorem $5.3$ of Hatcher, see [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch5.pdf).